# How to make a Static Rectangle shape in pymunk?

Tags: python, pygame, game-physics, physics, pymunk

My question is pretty straightforward I just wanna know a way to make a static body, which is a rectangle using pymunk. I tried reading the docs and found out about Segments, but couldn't really understand it. So any kind of help is very much appriciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you can use the static body already attached to the Space, or you make a new one. To create a rectangle, either you provide the corners to the Poly constructor (as shown below), or you use the shorthand Poly.create_box method.

```
space = pymunk.Space()
rectangle = pymunk.Poly(space.static_body, [(10,10),(20,10),(20,15),(10,15)])
space.add(rectangle)
```

Note that static bodies are not supposed to be moved after they have been added to space. So if you need to move the rectangle, you can use a kinematic body instead.

Comment: Thank dude it works ! I also found that you can use another way I posted below.

Answer (score 1):

viblo's methode works. As well as this

```
def create_rectangle_static(space,pos_x,pos_y,width,height):

    body = pymunk.Body(body_type=pymunk.Body.STATIC)
    
    body.position = (pos_x,pos_y)
    shape = pymunk.Poly.create_box(body,(width,height))
    space.add(body,shape)
```